# Selección de las líneas de un marco de datos de multi-index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

Quiero obtener las líneas del siguiente cuadro de datos multiíndice `monthly_sales`:

```
                                    date    item_price  item_cnt_day
                                     min    max mean    sum
date_block_num  shop_id item_id             
0               1       27          2013-01-12  2013-01-12  1890.0  1.0
                        29          2013-01-26  2013-01-26  1890.0  1.0
                        32          2013-01-05  2013-01-22  221.0   7.0
                        95          2013-01-28  2013-01-28  193.0   1.0
                        98          2013-01-03  2013-01-16  268.0   5.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1               1       22091       2013-02-18  2013-02-28  63.0    3.0
                        22092       2013-02-02  2013-02-23  64.0    11.0
                        22130       2013-02-23  2013-02-23  221.0   1.0
                        22151       2013-02-09  2013-02-09  268.0   1.0
                        22154       2013-02-22  2013-02-22  657.0   1.0
```

Iterando en las filas del siguiente cuadro de datos de `test`:

```
    ID  shop_id item_id
0   0   5   5037
1   1   5   5320
2   2   5   5233
3   3   5   5232
4   4   5   5268
```

Entonces intenté:

```
for i, row in test.iterrows():
  print("row['shop_id']: ", row['shop_id'], " row['item_id']: ", row['item_id'])
  print(sales_monthly.loc[sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(1) == row['shop_id'] & any(sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(2) == row['item_id'])])
  sales_item_shop = sales_monthly.loc[
    sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(1) == 5 
    & any(sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(2) == 5037)]
```

Pero no me parece devuelver la dataframe que esta relacionada con la iteracion :

```
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5037
                                     date            item_price item_cnt_day
                                      min        max       mean          sum
date_block_num shop_id item_id                                              
0              1       27      2013-01-12 2013-01-12     1890.0          1.0
                       29      2013-01-26 2013-01-26     1890.0          1.0
                       32      2013-01-05 2013-01-22      221.0          7.0
                       95      2013-01-28 2013-01-28      193.0          1.0
                       98      2013-01-03 2013-01-16      268.0          5.0
...                                   ...        ...        ...          ...
1              1       22091   2013-02-18 2013-02-28       63.0          3.0
                       22092   2013-02-02 2013-02-23       64.0         11.0
                       22130   2013-02-23 2013-02-23      221.0          1.0
                       22151   2013-02-09 2013-02-09      268.0          1.0
                       22154   2013-02-22 2013-02-22      657.0          1.0
```

En efecto, parece que deberia slecionar la linea con el subindex `shop_id == 5`, `item_id == 5037` y me devuelve lineas con `shop_id == 1` y `item_id` que no estan relacionada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `loc`, esto es posible sólo en conjunción con `pd.IndexSlice`.

```
sales_monthly.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, [row['shop_id']],[row['item_id']]], :]
```

El primer colon `:` en `pd.IndexSlice[:, [row['shop_id']],[row['item_id']]], :]` significa cortar a través del primer nivel. A medida que la profundidad del nivel que se está consultando aumenta, será necesario especificar más rebanadas, una por cada nivel que se rebane. Sin embargo, no necesitará especificar más niveles más allá del que se está cortando.